# Sencha production build works on the computers browser, but not the phones?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, mobile-application

I'm attempting to create a production build to run my app as a web application. At first I ran into a whole bunch of errors when trying to do the production build but I've worked through those and now it builds and runs in my computers web browser with no errors (no errors or warnings in the Console). Everything functions as it should.

When I try to access it through the browser on my phone however (iPhone, Safari) I get nothing but a blue screen. If I upload the entire (unminified) project, I can load it on my phone (after about 2 minutes) but not when I've run 'sencha app build production' or 'sencha app build testing'.

Any idea what might be causing this or how I could go about finding out?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any error in the console on the iPhone ?

Comment: The only error I get is "JavaScript Error on Line 4658 - (url)/sdk/sencha-touch.js - JavaScript execution exceeded timeout."

I've thrown in some console log statements around the place and it seems to be timing out when I'm declaring a whole bunch of xtypes ie:

Comment: (gets here)
var editor = {
  xtype: 'editor'
};
var main = {
  xtype: 'main'
};
etc etc.
(doesn't get here)

Comment: Ok so I've tried testing it on a few different phones / browsers. It doesn't work on my iPhone (3, 4.2.1) or someone elses Android (an older model) but it is working on newer iPhones. Is there some known compatibility issue that could be causing this / is it fixable?